# Eliminate a variable from two equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a set of two equations with three variables `u,o,d`. I want to eliminate either `u` or `d` from these equations.

```
2 (1 + u^2/d^2)^(1/4) == Sqrt[d] ((1 + (o - u)^2/d^2)^(1/4) + (1 + (o + u)^2/d^2)^(1/4))


2/3 (1/d)^(3/2) == (1/(4 d)) \[Pi] (o (-(1 + (o - u)^2/d^2)^(1/4) + (1 + (o + u)^2/d^2)^(1/4)) + u ((1 + (o - u)^2/d^2)^(1/4) + (1 + (o + u)^2/d^2)^(1/4)) + d ((1 + (o - u)^2/d^2)^(3/4) - (1 + (o + u)^2/d^2)^(3/4)))
```

So far I have tried using `Eliminate`, `Reduce`, `Solve`. After failing to get any output after several minutes, I eventually have to abort the evaluation. I cannot even seem to simplify these equations further. Any idea on how I can proceed? (Edit: My goal is to obtain a plot of u and d vs o.)

Comment: Numerical result should also be fine considering that I just want to obtain a plot of d vs o and u vs o eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain plots, you can use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) to generate [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) solutions for `d[o]` and `u[o]`. First, here are your equations:

```
eq1 = 2 (1+u^2/d^2)^(1/4) == Sqrt[d] ((1+(o-u)^2/d^2)^(1/4)+(1+(o+u)^2/d^2)^(1/4));

eq2 = 2/3 (1/d)^(3/2)==(1/(4 d)) \[Pi] (o (-(1+(o-u)^2/d^2)^(1/4)+(1+(o+u)^2/d^2)^(1/4))+u ((1+(o-u)^2/d^2)^(1/4)+(1+(o+u)^2/d^2)^(1/4))+d ((1+(o-u)^2/d^2)^(3/4)-(1+(o+u)^2/d^2)^(3/4)));
```

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), we will need an initial condition. So

```
{di, ui} = {d, u} /. FindRoot[{eq1, eq2} /. o->-1, {{d, .5}, {u, .1}}]
```

> {0.384684, 0.144757}

Next, we need to turn your equations into an ODE, and use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
{dsol, usol} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    D[eq1 /. {d->d[o], u->u[o]}, o],
    D[eq2 /. {d->d[o], u->u[o]}, o],
    u[-1] == ui,
    d[-1] == di
    },
    {d, u},
    {o, -5, 2}
];
```

Finally, here's a visualization of the result:

```
Plot[{dsol[t], usol[t]}, {t, -5, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's neat! Thanks.